# Having trouble moving object in a screen in python using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am a nubie in pygame and python overall. I started a simple helicopter game project yesterday but i cant figure out why my helicopter is not moving.

I followed exactly the same pattern as the youtube tutorial i watched but it still couldnt get the image to move.

```py
import pygame

#GLOBAL CONSTANTS_______________________________________________
pygame.init()

screen_height = 600
screen_width = 1200

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
title = pygame.display.set_caption("Helicpter game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 10

heli = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\rahul\Downloads\heli1.jpg")
heli = pygame.transform.scale(heli, (150, 150))
```

```py
def helicopter(x, y):
    screen.blit(heli, (x, y))

x = (0 * screen_width)
y = (0.5 * screen_height)

change_y = 0

gameExit = False
while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            change_y = -2


        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            change_y = 2

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key ==  pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
           change_y = 0

    change_y += y

    screen.fill(white)
    helicopter(x, y)

    pygame.display.flip()

clock.tick(FPS)
pygame.quit
```

It dosent give me any error messages but the image does not move at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to change the variable `y` rather than `change_y`:

<s>`change_y += y`</s>

```py
y += change_y
```

Note, the coordinate which defines the location of the image is `y`. `change_y` is used to modify this location.